# Covering the first element or block of the page when scrolling downwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to achieve an effect like this http://www.offset.com/
as you can see when it scrolls it slowly covering the carousel rather than scrolling with it.

I've tried using background fixed but the problem is the elements inside it will not stay in its position

Maybe there is a good technique in achieving this, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is called parallax scrolling here is an example of how to do this using **Jquery**  :

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/apederson/z93R7/)**

```
// Y axis scroll speed
var velocity = 0.5;

function update(){ 
    var pos = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    $('.container').each(function() { 
        var $element = $(this);
        // subtract some from the height b/c of the padding
        var height = $element.height()-18;
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '50% ' + Math.round((height - pos) * velocity) + 'px'); 
    }); 
};

$(window).bind('scroll', update);
```

an other example it might help **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9R4hZ/40/)**